# How to enable button when multiple selection is done and how to disable other choices?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have 10 different choices in my view. I want to enable "Devam Et" button when any of 10 choices are made. It sounds easy but critical part is as following...When I click any of the first 8 buttons, I want to disable the last 2 buttons if they are selected and also if I select any of the last two options, I want to disable all the other 8 options if they are selected.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The code of the first 3 button configuration lines is as following...Remaining ones are same as these.

```
VStack{
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.tap1.toggle()
                            }) {
                                ZStack {
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(self.tap1 ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)) : Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.936548737, green: 0.936548737, blue: 0.936548737, alpha: 1)))
                                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                    if self.tap1 {
                                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                    }
                                }.padding(.leading, 40)
                            }
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text("Diyabet")
                                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
                                .padding(.trailing, 200)
                                Spacer()
                        }.padding(.bottom, 10)
                        
                        
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.tap2.toggle()
                               
                                
                            }) {
                               ZStack {
                                   Rectangle()
                                       .fill(self.tap2 ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)) : Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.936548737, green: 0.936548737, blue: 0.936548737, alpha: 1)))
                                       .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                   if self.tap2 {
                                       Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                   }
                               }.padding(.leading, 40)
                            }
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text("Yüksek Tansiyon")
                                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
                                .padding(.trailing, 130)
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding(.bottom, 10)
                    
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.tap3.toggle()
                                
                            }) {
                                ZStack {
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(self.tap3 ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)) : Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.936548737, green: 0.936548737, blue: 0.936548737, alpha: 1)))
                                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                    if self.tap3 {
                                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                                    }
                                }.padding(.leading, 40)
                            }
button1
```

}

The code for "Devam Et" button is as following...

```
var button1: some View{
      

  return  Button(action: {
        if self.tap1 == true || self.tap2 == true || self.tap3 == true || self.tap4 == true || self.tap5 == true || self.tap6 == true || self.tap7 == true || self.tap8 == true   {
        self.tap11.toggle()
        }
        else if self.tap9 == true {
        self.tap11.toggle()

        }
        else if self.tap10 == true {
        self.tap11.toggle()
        }
        
    }) {
        Text("Devam Et")
        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 30)
        .padding()
        .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.3101329505, green: 0.193462044, blue: 0.3823927939, alpha: 1)))
        .cornerRadius(40)
        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 20.0, x: 20, y: 10)
        .padding(.bottom, 70)
    }.background(
                NavigationLink(destination: destinationView, isActive: $tap11) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .hidden()
            )
        }

    @ViewBuilder
    var destinationView: some View {
        if tap1 || tap2 || tap3 || tap4 || tap5 || tap6 || tap7 || tap8 || tap9 || tap10{
            entrance5()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> **TL;DR:** Result video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPFtu.jpg
>
> Result output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUnvG.jpg

Alright, this is a bit of a lengthy answer, before that I'll comment on some of your previous code:

It's not really a good choice to keep every boolean in their respective field, as you noticed it's really hard to keep track of them. Instead, you could have some sort of a struct that keeps track of every choice that you are providing.

What you also need is a proper state tracking, currently you need 3 type of state:

1. Standard state: Nothing has selected, yet.
2. Multiple choice state: There can be multiple selections, except the exclusive selections.
3. Exclusive choice state: Only one can be selected, in their respective group.

You also need to integrate it to your choices, to determine which kind you have selected in the list.

Last but not least, it should be handled outside of your current view, like in an interactor.

Here is the full code, ready to be tested in Playgrounds:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

enum ContentType {
    case standard
    case exclusive
}

enum ContentState {
    case none
    case multipleChoice
    case exclusiveChoice
}

struct ContentChoice: Identifiable {
    var id: String { title }
    
    let title: String
    let type: ContentType
    var isSelected: Bool = false
    var isDisabled: Bool = false
}

class ContentInteractor: ObservableObject, ContentChoiceViewDelegate {
    @Published var choices: [ContentChoice] = []
    @Published var state: ContentState = .none {
        didSet {
            print("state is now: \(state)")
            
            switch state {
            case .none:
                exclusiveChoices.forEach { choices[$0].isDisabled = false }
                standardChoices.forEach { choices[$0].isDisabled = false }
            case .multipleChoice:
                exclusiveChoices.forEach { choices[$0].isDisabled = true }
            case .exclusiveChoice:
                standardChoices.forEach { choices[$0].isDisabled = true }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var exclusiveChoices: [Int] {
        choices.indices.filter { choices[$0].type == .exclusive }
    }
    private var standardChoices: [Int] {
        choices.indices.filter { choices[$0].type == .standard }
    }
    
    private var isExclusiveChoiceSelected: Bool {
        choices.filter { $0.type == .standard && $0.isSelected }.count > 0
    }
    private var selectedMultipleChoiceCount: Int {
        choices.filter { $0.type == .standard && $0.isSelected }.count
    }
    
    func didToggleChoice(_ choice: ContentChoice) {
        guard let index = choices.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == choice.id }) else {
            fatalError("No choice found with the given id.")
        }
        
        // This is where the whole algorithm lies.
        switch state {
            // Phase 1:
            // If the user has not made any choice (state == .none),
            // Enabling a `.standard` choice should lock the `.exclusive` choices.
            // And vice versa.
            case .none:
                choices[index].isSelected.toggle()

                switch choice.type {
                case .standard:
                    state = .multipleChoice
                case .exclusive:
                    state = .exclusiveChoice
                }

            // Phase 2:
            // If the user is in multiple choice state,
            // They can only select multiple choices. If any of the multiple choice
            // is still selected, it should stay as is.
            // If every choice is deselected, it should return the state to `.none`.
            case .multipleChoice:
                choices[index].isSelected.toggle()

                switch choice.type {
                case .standard:
                    if selectedMultipleChoiceCount == 0 {
                        state = .none
                    }
                case .exclusive:
                    preconditionFailure("Unexpected choice selection.")
                }
            
            // Phase 3:
            // If the user is in a not-answering state,
            // They can only change it within themselves.
            // If every choice is deselected, it should return the state to `.none`.
            // Also, every exclusive choice is, exclusive.
            // Hence, if one of them is selected, the others should be deselected.
        case .exclusiveChoice:
            switch choice.type {
            case .standard:
                preconditionFailure("Unexpected choice selection.")
            case .exclusive:
                let isSelecting = !choices[index].isSelected
                
                if isSelecting {
                    exclusiveChoices.forEach { choices[$0].isSelected = false }
                } else {
                    state = .none
                }
            }
            
            choices[index].isSelected.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    func didSelectSubmit() {
        print("Current selection:", choices.filter { $0.isSelected }.map { $0.title })
    }
}

protocol ContentChoiceViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didToggleChoice(_ choice: ContentChoice)
    func didSelectSubmit()
}

struct ContentChoiceView: View {
    let choice: ContentChoice
    weak var delegate: ContentChoiceViewDelegate!
    
    init(choice: ContentChoice, delegate: ContentChoiceViewDelegate) {
        self.choice = choice
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.delegate.didToggleChoice(self.choice)
            }) {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(self.choice.isSelected ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005, green: 0.2352941185, blue: 0.1019607857, alpha: 1)) : Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.936548737, green: 0.936548737, blue: 0.936548737, alpha: 1)))
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    if self.choice.isSelected {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    }
                }.padding(.leading, 40)
            }.disabled(self.choice.isDisabled)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text(choice.title)
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
//                .padding(.trailing, 200)
                Spacer()
        }.padding(.bottom, 10)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var interactor: ContentInteractor
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(interactor.choices) { choice in
                ContentChoiceView(choice: choice, delegate: self.interactor)
            }
            Spacer()
            submitButton
        }.padding(.vertical, 70)
    }
        
    var submitButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.interactor.didSelectSubmit()
        }) {
            Text("Devam Et")
             .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
             .foregroundColor(Color.white)
             .frame(width: 200, height: 30)
             .padding()
             .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.3101329505, green: 0.193462044, blue: 0.3823927939, alpha: 1)))
             .cornerRadius(40)
             .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 20.0, x: 20, y: 10)
        }
    }
}

let interactor = ContentInteractor()

["Diyabet", "Yuksek Tansiyon", "Astim"].forEach { title in
    interactor.choices.append(ContentChoice(title: title, type: .standard))
}
["Soylememeyi Tercih Ederim", "Hicbirini Gecirmedim"].forEach { title in
    interactor.choices.append(ContentChoice(title: title, type: .exclusive))
}

let contentView = ContentView(interactor: interactor)

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(contentView)
```

Comment: I'm very new to Swift and Swift UI as well. Pardon me if I'm asking a doll question but I'm creating an app with swift UI view and the all my codes are in there. I don't know how to integrate the code you wrote in playgrounds into my view

Comment: Well, Playground is just there to make it testable without the whole project. Except the `PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(contentView)` part, the rest is just plug & play, move the new classes within their respective files in your project, then use the new `ContentView` in somewhere in your project so it would be shown, that's it.

Comment: I receive 'Expressions are not allowed at the top level' error when I add the ["Diyabet", "Yuksek Tansiyon", "Astim"].forEach { title in
    interactor.choices.append(ContentChoice(title: title, type: .standard))
}
["Soylememeyi Tercih Ederim", "Hicbirini Gecirmedim"].forEach { title in
    interactor.choices.append(ContentChoice(title: title, type: .exclusive))
}

Comment: They're only for example, you should not directly use that. And the error probably is about not putting them in the right place. There should be a method that lets you create the interactor, and fill the choices, and then passing it to your view itself. As a small suggestion, if the content is static, you could set it in the initializer directly, like: `@Published var choices: [ContentChoice] = [ContentChoice(title: "Title", type: .standard)]`

Comment: Should I create a class for let interactor = ContentInteractor()

["Diyabet", "Yuksek Tansiyon", "Astim"].forEach { title in
    interactor.choices.append(ContentChoice(title: title, type: .standard))
}
["Soylememeyi Tercih Ederim", "Hicbirini Gecirmedim"].forEach { title in
    interactor.choices.append(ContentChoice(title: title, type: .exclusive))
}

let contentView = ContentView(interactor: interactor).  part ? and what should I write into the preview section to see the preview. Is it ContentView(interactor: interactor) ?I'm again sorry for not getting this right.

Comment: No worries, you're right about the preview part, the only thing you'd need to provide is `ContentView(interactor: interactor)` to preview. You should be having a method/class that constructs the interactor as you wish. You may want to check `EnvironmentObject` and some other basic SwiftUI concepts to get a better grasp with what you're trying to achieve.